# How to avoid using viewbag in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, viewbag

I am new to learning ASP.NET Core MVC. Currently I'm learning how to avoid using viewbag in any of my code since I was told it was not good practice. I would like to know how can I avoid using viewbag when passing method data to the controller and displaying the data in the View. A copy of my simple code is below.

This is my controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.FV = 0;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(FutureValueModel model)
    {
        ViewBag.FV = model.CalculateFutureValue();
        return View(model);
    }
```

This is my model class:

```
  public class FutureValueModel
  {
      public decimal MonthlyInvestment { get; set; }
      public decimal YearlyInteresRate { get; set; }
      public int Years { get; set; }
      public decimal FV { get; set; }

      public decimal CalculateFutureValue()
      {
           int months = Years * 12;
           decimal monthlyInterestRate = YearlyInteresRate / 12 / 100;
           decimal futureValue = 0;

           for (int i = 0; i < months; i++)
           {
               futureValue = (futureValue + MonthlyInvestment) * (1 + monthlyInterestRate);
           }
           return futureValue;
      }
   }
```

Here's the view:

```
   @model FutureValueModel

   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Future Interest Calculator";
    }

    <h1>Future Value Calculator</h1>

    <form asp-action="Index" method="post">
        <div>
           <label asp-for="MonthlyInvestment">Monthly Investment:</label>
           <input asp-for="MonthlyInvestment" />
        </div>
        <div>
           <label asp-for="YearlyInteresRate">Yearly Interest Rate:</label>
           <input asp-for="YearlyInteresRate" />
        </div>
        <div>
           <label asp-for="Years">Number of Years:</label>
           <input asp-for="Years" />
        </div>
        <div>
           <label>Future Value:</label>
           <input value="@ViewBag.Fv.ToString("C2")" />
       </div>
       <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
       <a asp-action="Index">Clear</a>
    </form>
```

I have been Googling daily for weeks now I have not been able to come up with a solution. I do not have a job where I can ask a fellow coding partner, so here I am on StackOverflow. FYI this code is from Murach's ASP.NET Core MVC book.

Comment: To be honest, the only alt I've seen to ViewBag is a custom ViewModel....that serves literally the same exact purpose as a ViewBag. I don't know why someone would say not to use ViewBag though I am open to a warranted explanation

Comment: Ok, well let me walk that back by one inch, the one strike against it is that ViewBag is a `dynamic` object, so in the name of upholding static typing technically you would want to steer toward a stricter ViewModel. But that's just object-oriented hair splitting: If you don't need that level of strictness then why spend the time to write out a ViewModel? In proper MVC structure you are *supposed to have a service layer anyway* so by the time the controller is passing a ViewBag/ViewModel to the View layer, everything should be well and validated by that point

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how can I avoid using viewbag when passing
> method data to the controller and displaying the data in the View.

If you don't want to use viewbag, you can use model to pass data like below:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new FutureValueModel();
            model.FV = 0;
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(FutureValueModel model)
        {
            model.FV= model.CalculateFutureValue();           
            return View(model);
        }
```

Index view:

```
    <div>
        <label>Future Value:</label>    
        <input value="@Model.FV.ToString("C2")" />
    </div>
```

result:
[image]